# Export alignment information during docx to html conversion - pandoc

Tags: pandoc, html, msword

I'm using pandoc in my website to allow my content creators to use Word, which would simplify developmnent immensely. The only issue I have is that Pandoc seems to output very little information about document styling. It's possible for me to manually re-add these with CSS later, but that somewhat defeats the pupose of using Word.

Hence my question. Can I get pandoc to spit out more information about how my document is structured, such that I can apply more generic styles and have the document looking comparable to how it was written.

Example, I've got a table with user-defined centre-aligned text (the person centred the text in Word). When I export my document to HTML using the following command:

`pandoc --from docx --to html --embed-resources --reference-doc ./reference.docx --section-divs`. (I'm streaming in the contents of the file via stdin, as it isn't guaranteed to be in a consistent location)`.

When the HTML comes back, the contents of the table elements are simply paragraphs. I'd like them to be wrapped in `<center>` tags or the equivalent - just something to identify that they need to be centred.

There's a number of examples like these that I'd like to introduce, but momentarily, centring text is a priority.

Thanks for any pointers